# Why does one MOSFET heat up very fast compared to the other MOSFET in this induction heater circuit?

Tags: mosfet, induction, overheat, induction-heater

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl08yr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll start off by saying this project is just an experiment I'm playing around with and is not the typical ZVS design you find everywhere. I wanted to make one that was actively switched so I could control the frequency of the work coil. The design works although I can't leave it running for more than about a minute because one MOSFET gets very hot but not the other MOSFET even though the circuit is symmetrical and both in theory should be doing the same amount of work. The MOSFETs are driving a toroidal transformer with 50 turns on the primary and a center tap connected to 18vdc and 8 turns of the secondary directly feeding the tank circuit and work coil. The drive circuit is a single tl494cn which has a push pull output stage and a control to adjust deadtime. This is also running on 18vdc to send a gate drive that is just under 18v. I was thinking that the rise time on the gate might be the cause but my scope shows they are very closely matched but no matter what I do one FET always heats up much faster than the other. Both are bolted to a solid copper slab for a heat sink which helped a lot but only delays the heating. The output at the work coil is not quite sinusoidal but seems like its a product of the FETs not switching when they should be. There is a small amount of gate ring but it peaks at about 2 volts probably because I use a 1.5 k gs resistor to discharge the gate. I decided to switch the gates around to see if the issue followed and sure enough the problem changed sides so it has to be something with the gate signal creating the issue even though the signal looks pretty clean with only a little bit of slope on the rising edge
[image: this is my scope reading showing the gate signal on the MOSFET in question, the green trace is from a current probe on the power input showing about 9 amps continuous load]

This is showing the gate signal on the MOSFET that gets too hot. The green trace is the input current from a current probe showing about 9 amps continuous load.

[image: this is the voltage waveform directly from the work coil]

This is the waveform at the work coil showing the asymmetry of the AC wave. I suspect the frequency is really high so the heating doesn't penetrate very far into the material but I can change that at any point once I figure out this heating issue.

Comment: Some concerns: 1. TL494 is not "push-pull output"; which C/E pins have you connected? 2. What's on everything else? In particular, what PWM is it set for? 3. 75R is a rather strong pull-up especially at 18V, have you checked the pin current and saturation voltage ratings for the TL494? 4. Are the MOSFETs really dissimilar? Which one(s) are you using?

Comment: The control pin is set to make the output transistors alternate. Push pull was the wrong way to describe that sorry if that confused anybody. 75ohms is very strong for a pull up and my logic behind that choice was to remove as much resistance in the path of the gate to improve the slope of the rising edge. So far it hasnt created any problems, the ic stays cool. I originally used 220 ohm resistors and i thought it might be too high to use as a gate resistor. The mosfets are both the same, i thought i made an edit to clear that up but they are toshiba 2sk2837 n channel 500v 20A Rds on .21 ohm